# Dark mode without JavaScript

Tags: php, html, css

I have a small website using only PHP, HTML, and CSS and want to add Dark Mode on it. I've found a lot solutions, but all of them use JavaScript. Is that possible to add Dark Mode without JS?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use JavaScript?

Comment: @Haem Yes. I want to find a solution without using JS. I just want to make a website complitely without it.

Comment: Is this a test project or serious one? What are your browser requirements? Is the user supposed to change theme on the fly? Do you have a server behind this?

Comment: @Dejan.S It's my hobby project. Yes, user supposed to change theme on the fly. I think that most of the users will have up-to-date browser. Sorry, I probably didn't understand your question about server. Is there a way using php without webserver like apache or nginx?

Comment: store a variable in php and use that to set your stylesheet

Comment: @Pete so it is possible to have a dark mode without using cookies or sessions!? I am not sure how it can be done, can you please explain it to me?

Comment: if you don't want to use cookies, session vars or js, how do you expect to do it? you are kind of ruling out all options there, apart from having a constant variable in your url that you check for

Comment: @Pete Sorry, my English is not as good as I want to. I misinterpreted your message. I'm trying to make it using cookies. I'm still not done yet, but when I will be I'll publish what I've made.

Comment: Your way to go is to use css variables and change those on the fly using Javascript, and save that in a cookie. Else you would have to post to a server and reload the site if you are not gone use javascript. To me it is just plain strange why anybody want to build a site without javascript in 2019. Don't take this the wrong way but I'm pretty sure your users are used to modern sites using modern browsers :). I would say this is what you need https://alligator.io/css/theming-custom-properties/

Comment: After spending some time I've come to the conclusion that I can't add a dark mode without reducing usability of my website. I'll do it with js; probably using darkmode.js. **Thank you** to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a *routing* element in your URL that determines (using server side logic) which set of cascading style sheets gets loaded.

For example in `http://foobar.com/dark/path/to/content` the `/dark/` part of the URL could make the server load your "dark" theme CSS files.

Comment: The first option looks cool, but I think that this solution will become the second option if I'll try to "prettify" the URL, and I don't really want to use the prettified URL as a solution for the dark theme.

Comment: You could also have a link that turns on the dark mode, sets a cookie then returns to where the user was. Then your service side logic reads the cookie and loads the relevant CSS accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

You already have all you need.  Browser detection is done with CSS following the [Media Queries Level 5](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#prefers-color-scheme) specification using a `prefers-color-scheme` media query for detection.  If you're familiar with responsive web-design with CSS then you already have all the knowledge - the only difference is that responsive CSS is about geography (sizes, columns, padding, spacing, font-size, etc.) and `prefers-color-scheme` is about ... well ... color.  Thomas Steiner ([@DenverCoder9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6255000/denvercoder9)) has an awesome article "[prefers-color-scheme: Hello darkness, my old friend](https://web.dev/prefers-color-scheme/)" that covers this.

If you are asking about PHP specifically then you are out of luck - there is no dark mode detection methodology for server side-processing.

- All efforts thus-far by the W3C *(and its sponsors)* has been focused on client-side / Jamstack.
- There is a recommendation by Thomas Steiner *(same guy)* to implement a [Proposed server-side client hint](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4162), but this has not been adopted *(yet?)* by the W3C or the browsers.
- Either way - there is a significant drawback in server-side detection *(both with Thomas' recommendation and my solution below)* in that the server will only know about a state change *(e.g. macOS "Auto" mode when night fall happens)* on the next server request, or more visibly, the first load of the page.

My recommendation is to leverage CSS / client-side only on this - Thomas gives some practical guidance on two methods,

1. 1x CSS with both color schemes supported, and
2. 2x CSS, with one being light and the other dark.  I've made a educative whitepaper applying some of these methods with the CSS framework Bootstrap at [vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark](https://github.com/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark) to show how easy that can be - without server-side processing.

Having said that - if you must insist on PHP or server-side detection there is no workaround - but one must use some JS.  The most efficient way is to leverage the [js-cookie/js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) project, and include the following code into your HTML pages:

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // code to set the `color_scheme` cookie
    var $color_scheme = Cookies.get("color_scheme");
    function get_color_scheme() {
      return (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) ? "dark" : "light";
    }
    function update_color_scheme() {
      Cookies.set("color_scheme", get_color_scheme());
    }
    // read & compare cookie `color-scheme`
    if ((typeof $color_scheme === "undefined") || (get_color_scheme() != $color_scheme))
      update_color_scheme();
    // detect changes and change the cookie
    if (window.matchMedia)
      window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addListener( update_color_scheme );
  </script>
```

And then your PHP will detect this cookie like this:

```php
  $color_scheme = isset($_COOKIE["color_scheme"]) ? $_COOKIE["color_scheme"] : false;
  if ($color_scheme === false) $color_scheme = 'light';  // fallback
```

Which you can use to load the CSS:

```php
  // Load the CSS for the correct color-scheme
  if ($color_scheme == 'dark') {
    ?><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark@0.0/dist/bootstrap-night.min.css"><?php
  } else {
    ?><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0.css/bootstrap.css"><?php
  }
```

Or, like this:

```php
  ?>You are in <?= $color_scheme ?> mode.<?php
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do a clone of the **css** and change the **background-color**, **buttons**... It's not really necessary really to use **JavaScript**

If you want to do just a **button for change the css**, i don't really know how to do it, but if you want to do **another webpage** but just for Dark Mode, just put the clone off the css that you created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to do it using php setcookie() and multiple css files.